# WCF Service 'The resource cannot be found.' after publish

Tags: web-services, wcf, deployment, publish

I have a MVC website and need a WCF service running to import data from an external source.

The service is located in a "Services" directory in the root of the application.
(http: //(Site name)/Services/Importer.svc - the contract is in the same folder)

It all works fine in my development environment, but the moment I publish it to the web server, it falls flat on its face with a 404 error.

I've found numerous posts of people having the same issues, but none of their solutions worked for me.

Here is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="APP_NAME.Services.Importer">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="APP_NAME.Services.IImporter" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any advice & guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 404 is a "not found" error, meaning your client cannot reach your host. So you have to start there when debugging this. You might need Fiddler to watch the traffic back and forth. You might also need to turn on extra logging on the client and host sides to capture the details.

Comment: I have tried this, I was unable to get any useful info from fiddler.